# Generic mapping tools problems

Tags: software-installation

I try alot to install GMT software in Ubuntu 17.04 .
I used these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gmt
```

after that when I write a gmt commands such as `psxy` there is this answer `psxy: command not found`
I also write `sudo gedit .bashrc` and in bashrc I write these commands as the following

```
export NETCDFHOME=/usr/lib
export GMTHOME=/usr/lib/gmt
export PATH=$PATH:$GMTHOME/bin
```

after this I close and again open the teminal and update that but the gmt commands are still not found.
I spend too much time. how can I solve this problem???
what should I do

Comment: Was the installation successful at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Check which GMT version you installed. I assume it is GMT 5 in which case all commands are to be preceded by `gmt`. For example: `gmt psxy`.